# Ordering an iPhone from different region

Tags: iphone, internationalization, unlock

So I ordered an iPhone SE from Apple.com It delivers in United States, But I Live in Georgia(Middle East) and The phone will be send to me by mail.

I ordered a phone with unlocked carrier but i'm still not sure if There are any problems with unlocking and using the phone with my local carrier? And if so how can i solve the problems?
Thank you.

Comment: I have bought iDevices from USA and middle-east and except for the feature difference (Facetime is disabled on iDevices in middle-east) they work without any issues. Moreover, Apple offers international warranty, so you do not have to ship it to the country of purchase to get it repaired (unless ofcourse, you don't have an Apple authorised service centre in your country).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good news is your country is not entirely locked out of the Apple ecosystem and you will be able to make an AppleID and host it in your country of Georgia and have access to the App Store.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204411

Past that, it’s not great news since many services will require you to have your AppleID hosted in a different country. Much of Apple’s offering is not directly offered to the country of Georgia. I lack experience on the cellular carriers, but since iPhone are sold in Turkey directly from Apple and from two resellers in Armenia - you likely have easy access to carriers to register the eSIM or put a physical GSM SIM in your new phone and have it work perfectly. There is zero hassle on swapping SIM at your convenience on unlocked phones from the US - no downside to buying from us other than you may have to ship it back for warranty service if Apple requests that when you ask for service. Nor many down sides, bit I can’t get you details lacking a good knowledge of carrier status in Georgia.

Also, you shouldn’t run into issue importing it after checking the Global Trade Compliance information that Apple publishes.

- https://www.apple.com/legal/more-resources/gtc.html